# Flex + Java store audio file on server

Tags: java, apache-flex, io, byte, flex4.6

I'm trying to store recorded audio message from Flex Mobile in remote server. On the server side I'm using java. When I record something it records and I'm sending ByteArray to server (BlazeDS) which is byte[] at server side - server java code creates for me that .mp3 file but when I try to play it I simply can't play - it shows duration of 00:00 but file size is about 400-500kbs for 3-4 sec recordings --- so I think problem is not in file operations but the way how I create mp3 file. Here's my code:

```
String path = "/Users/lbstr/sound";

        File dir = new File(path); 

        if(!dir.exists()){
            if(dir.mkdirs()){
                System.out.println("REPORT: DIRECTORY CREATED!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("REPORT: ERROR ON CREATING DIRECTORY");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("DIRECTORY EXISTS!");
        }


        File file = new File(dir,"voice.mp3");

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);



        fop.write(bytes);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();
```

On the flex side there's not a big deal - I'm just using Microphone and getting ByteArray data when user clicks on stop button.

Where's the problem & how should I solve it? Any suggestions is highly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest to sniff data you're streaming into (I suppose) AMF protocol by some utility like this: [http://www.charlesproxy.com/](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) so you can understand what are you streaming (what format, if correct, etc). By this analisys I think we can help you further.

Comment: Are you sure that the file data you send over as byte array really describes a mp3 file? Considering the size I would say it is a wave file.

Comment: Does Flex mobile Microphone records sound as wave by default? its my first experience in recording - save to server & playback..